# How to create two pipelines in a jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this scenario i am setting up but within a single jenkinsfile but for some reason it is not working as expected.
My idea was to have 2 pipelines

1st pipeline
 -git checkout
 -build
 -Test

2nd pipeline

if first build from the first pipeline was successful, then

-re-do the first 3 stages from 1st pipeline
-zip the build results
-and push to nexus.

```
node {
    stages....
}

node2 {
    stages...
}
```

the above approach is viewed as a single pipeline and not two as i expected.
..is this however feasible within a single jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you can do this in one pipeline. Just ensure that if the git build fails, make the node on your pipeline fail. That way you will only reach Nexus following a successful build.

I hope this helps!